# Testing private server using multiple connexions

Tags: bash, server, integration-testing

In my company, I have have to test if a server is responding correctly.

The main test is to ask people (form the company) to connect simultaneously to the server at the same time.

I want to automate this procedure and doing it with one computer. My idea is to make a script that add several ip adresses to my PC and send a ping with all of them to the server.

Is it something doable ? Or maybe is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: ping will not establish *connections* between your clients and server

Comment: As dtmilano said, ping doesn't establish connections. Ping elicits responses from the host or gateway.

Comment: So is it possible to make a simple connexion (open then close) still with bash or should I use another language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure its do able in bash but there are many opensource tools which let you perform more complex operations right out of the box so get useful result quicker. I used Tsung in a similar  situation and was able to investigate  the systems response to varying the rate of adding connection more easily  than if i was  using bash. It  was also easier to massively parallelise threads to simulate hundreds of users.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for :)